# glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer

Tags: c, pointers, free, glibc

I have the following problem with this segment of code. Can some one please help?

Note: QueueItem is being created on a different thread.

```
WorkItem * Dequeue(Queue ** Q)    
{    
    if(QueueIsEmpty(*Q)) return NULL;

    QueueItem * tmp = (*Q)->Head;
    (*Q)->Head = ((*Q)->Head)->NextItem;
    WorkItem * retval = tmp->workItem;
    free(tmp); //Generates  glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer
    return retval;
}
```

edit This function is protected on access when multiple threads are running.

```
WorkItem * DequeueSynchronous(Queue ** Q)
{
    WorkItem * retval;
    pthread_mutex_lock((*Q)->QueMutex);
    retval = Dequeue (Q);
    pthread_mutex_unlock((*Q)->QueMutex);
    return retval;
}
```

(*Q)->Head; is allocated my malloc.

```
Queue * Queue_Init(pthread_mutex_t * mutex)
{
    Queue * retval = (Queue *)malloc(sizeof(Queue *));
    retval->Head = retval->Tail =NULL;
    retval->QueMutex = mutex;
    return retval;
}

void Enqueue (Queue * Q, WorkItem * WI)
{

   if(!Q)return;
   QueueItem * QI = (QueueItem *) malloc(sizeof(QueueItem *));
   QI->workItem = WI;
   QI->NextItem = NULL;

   if(QueueIsEmpty(Q))
   {
       Q->Head = Q->Tail = QI;
       return;
   }

   Q->Tail->NextItem = QI;
   Q->Tail = QI;
}

void EnqueueSynchronous (Queue * Q, WorkItem * WI)
{

   pthread_mutex_lock(Q->QueMutex);
   Enqueue (Q, WI);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(Q->QueMutex);
}
```

Also thanks for the input, I will look at valgrind.

EDIT 2

```
typedef struct {
    char ** FileNames;
    int  ** Results;
    int NumOfItems;
}WorkItem;

typedef struct QI{
    WorkItem * workItem;
    struct QI * NextItem;
}QueueItem;

typedef struct {
    QueueItem * Head, * Tail;
    pthread_mutex_t * QueMutex;
}Queue;
```

Dequeue is called -`Dequeue(&WorkQue)`
All threads that call `Dequeue` were given `&WorkQue` as part of their args;

```
typedef struct{
    int ThreadID;
    WorkItem * workItem;
    char ** keywordsArray;
    int nKeywords;
    Queue ** WorkQueue, ** WorkCompletedQ;   
}ThreadArgs;

 pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];
ThreadArgs threadArgs[NTHREADS];

for(i=0;i<NTHREADS;i++)
{
    threadArgs[i].ThreadID=i;
    threadArgs[i].workItem = Dequeue(&WorkQue);
    threadArgs[i].WorkQueue = &WorkQue;
    threadArgs[i].WorkCompletedQ = &WorkCompletedQ;
    threadArgs[i].nKeywords=_kwlist->length;
    threadArgs[i].keywordsArray = ListToArray(*_kwlist);
}    

for(i=0;i<NTHREADS;i++)
{
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, WorkerThread,(void *)&(threadArgs[i]));
}
```

each thread calls dequeue using `myWork = DequeueSynchronous(myThreadArgs->WorkQueue);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your updated code, I think you're having memory corruption due to these lines:

```
Queue * retval = (Queue *)malloc(sizeof(Queue *));
```

Note that you're only allocating enough for a pointer to a Queue there - you should instead write:

```
Queue * retval = (Queue *)malloc(sizeof(Queue)); // version one
```

Or better:

```
Queue * retval = (Queue *)malloc(sizeof(*retval)); // version two
```

The second version is better, because it's robust to changes in the type of `retval`.

Both of these lines say "allocate enough space for a Queue, and set the queue pointer `retval` to point to it". Your previous line said "allocate enough space for a Queue **pointer**, and set the queue pointer `retval` to point to it". The old version caused an under allocation (since the structure was almost certainly larger than a pointer).

Then, when you assign to parts of the Queue structure that are past the space you've actually allocated, you stamp some other part of memory. I suspect that this causes you to stamp some of `malloc()`s internal control data, which is what causes the invalid free later on. You will need to change all of your `malloc()` calls to malloc the size of the structure rather than the size of the pointer.

Note that you should also [not cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). In my opinion, your final `malloc()` statements should look like this:

```
Queue * retval = malloc(sizeof(*retval));
```

If that doesn't fix it, can you edit your question to include:

1. The definition of the Queue structure
2. How you're calling `DequeueSynchronous` (or, where the `*Q` becomes `**Q`)

---

Unrelatedly, note that you also have a bug where you don't clear the tail when the list becomes empty after a dequeue. I suspect you may need to write:

```
(*Q)->Head = ((*Q)->Head)->NextItem;
if ((*Q)->Head == NULL) (*Q)->Tail = NULL;
```

This will clear the tail if there's now no head in the queue.

Comment: I'm using the gdb already, but will give valgrind a shot. A double free is unlikely.
thanks for the input

Comment: @chris I think I've found your problem - see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks @Tim, your advice on malloc helped reduce most of the invalid read and write that was showing up on valgrind. I was in the process of changing it to V1 but I liked v2 better and used that. And Also my glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer error. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing intrinsically wrong with this, as far as we can see. But the problem must be that `tmp` (in other words, `(*Q)->Head` on entry to the function) isn't a pointer to a block allocated by `malloc()`. If it was allocated in any other way -- or if it's a pointer into the middle of a block rather than the start -- then you can't free it with `free()`.

It's also possible that it's been freed already; perhaps your multiple threads are causing it to be freed more than once.

Comment: Well (*Q)->Head was allocated  by malloc and when I'm running multiple threads no more than one at a time has access to Queue. Thanks for the input.